# How to enable Highcharts scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, highcharts

I tried doing the

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
}
```

But it didnt work.

I tried using the highcharts.js that comes with highstocks.. that did not work either.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 14):

If your code still doesn't work, you could try changing this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

with this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

and you can add this :

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
},
```

finally, you can add this for how many data points you want to view at a time, example " min: 6 " :

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    min: 6   <!-- LOOK at this -->
},
```

Answer (score 7):

A similar question has already been answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518686/highcharts-scroll-through-axis).

You can refer to this: [How to enable scrollbars in highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/fj6d2/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    min: 6
},

legend: {
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 100,
    align: 'right'
},

scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer, scrollbar can be added via highstock js.
I managed to implement an elegant and simple scrollbar solution to my column chart, using only highcharts js, without highstock, as follows:

```
chart: {
   type: 'column',
   scrollablePlotArea: {
   minWidth: {{ count($period_interval_categories) * 70}},
        // nr of interval data x (40 + 30) where 40 are column width pixels and
        // 30 is additional distancing between columns;
        // Increase spacing pixels if needed
   scrollPositionX: 1
   }
},
plotOptions: {
   column: {
       stacking: 'normal',
       pointWidth: 40, // column width in pixels
       dataLabels: {
           // enabled: true
       }
    }
},
```

where $period_interval_categories represents in my chart the period on x axis consisting of days, weeks, months, etc.

[image]