# Highcharts scrollbar not working properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scrollbar

I have columnrange graph set up which is working perfectly fine. I grab the data required using ajax and recreate the graph everytime on user click event. I am trying to add x-axis scrollbar but it is not workin gporperly. I have to change the js import to highstock. and if I chnage the min value to any number it does not work. The `data.cat` brings back 32 categories, without the scrolling feature it all looks very squashed.

here is the graph

```
$('#projects').highcharts({
                                        'chart':{
                                            'type':'columnrange',
                                            /* events: { 
                                                 load: function (event) { 
                                                     $('#projects').width(800); 
                                                     } 
                                                }*/
                                        },
                                        'exporting':{
                                            'enabled':true
                                            },

                                        'title':{
                                            text:'Projects in progress, '+data.asaarea
                                            },
                                        xAxis:{
                                            categories:data.cat,
                                            min: 10
                                            },
                                        'yAxis':{
                                            'title':'Date',
                                            'type':'datetime',
                                            'dateTimeLabelFormats':{                
                                                'month':'%b %Y'
                                            },
                                            'min':Date.UTC(2010,00,01)
                                        },

                                        'tooltip':{
                                            formatter: function(){
                                                var percentage = '';
                                                if(this.series.name == "Actual"){
                                                    var data = "PROJECT="+this.x + "&StartDATE="+this.point.low;

                                                    var percent = $.ajax({
                                                        url: "index.php?r=ViewWebprojectreport/getPercent",
                                                        type: "GET",
                                                       dataType:"html",
                                                        data: data,
                                                        global: false,
                                                        async:false,
                                                        success:function(data){
                                                            return data;                                            
                                                        }
                                                    }).responseText;

                                                    percentage = percent +'% Complete<br>';
                                                }
                                                return  percentage + '<b>' +this.series.name + ':</b> '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b, %Y', this.point.low) + ' - ' +  Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b, %Y', this.point.high) +'<br/>' ;
                                                  }  
                                            },
                                        'legend':{
                                            'enabled':true
                                            },
                                        credits: {
                                            enabled: false
                                        },
                                        scrollbar: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        },
                                        'series':[
                                                    {
                                                    'name':'Forecast',
                                                    'data':data.data,
                                                    'color': 'blue' 
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                    'name':'Actual',
                                                    'data':data.complete,
                                                    'color': 'green'    
                                                    }
                                                ]

                                    }); // end of columngraph
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/4GYu3/)

Comment: What doesn't work? For example `min: 25`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/4GYu3/2/ works fine. Regarding scrollbar - you are right, you need to use Highstock.

Comment: why is it `min:25`? what if I dynamically change the number of categories and data in series. with `min:25` it does not display properly?

Comment: But what do you expect? Highcharts doesn't calculate anything to make chart wider just because you enabled scrollbar.. I think you need to set for example `max: categories.length > 5 ? 5 : categories.length` so you will have condition if set max or not (and the same for scrollbar). Where categories is your variable with all categories.

Comment: Have you checked this answer if it works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11464098

Comment: Agreed with pawel's comment. For enabling scrollbar we need to first add the highstock.js and second thing we need to add (scrollbar:{enabled:true} and add the max and min attribute in xAxis:. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>

<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

I have included necessary jscripts. To make a dynamic scroll bar i used JQuery to increase div length. Containers of the graph

```
<div id="weekly_status_graph" style="height:800px;display:none;width: 1120px;padding-top: 20px;"></div>
<div id="weekly_status_graph_line" style="height:800px;display:none;width: 1120px;padding-top: 20px;"></div>
<div id="weekly_status_graph_dialog" style="height:800px;display:none;width: 1120px;padding-top: 20px;"></div>
```

Adjust size as appropriate

```
if(data.type == "column"){
        $('#weekly_status_graph_line').hide();
        $('#weekly_status_graph').show();       
        columnGraph(data);
    }else if(data.type == "line"){
        $('#weekly_status_graph').hide();
        $("#weekly_status_graph_line").css("width","1830px");
        $("#weekly_status_graph_line").css("margin-left","-0px");
        $('#weekly_status_graph_line').show();      
        lineGraph(data);
    }
```