# Highcharts: X-axis, plot points and horizontal scrolling

Tags: highcharts

Not sure how to word this, but here goes.

I want my X-axis to be at 1 day intervals, however, I want the **actual plot points between days to be at a 5 minute interval**. How do I do this? And since there are so many plot points, I'm sure I will need some sort of horizontal scrolling option?  Right now my chart is so compact!

*Note: Every plot point is a 5 minute time interval starting at 7am and ending at 11pm*

Code is below:

```
  $(function () {
       $('#container').highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        credits: {
        text: 'XML Feed',
        href: 'utlfeed.aspx?campus=PR&room=B325'
      },
        title: {
            text:   'PR-B325 Room Utilization',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
        text:   'Source: FreePC',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
            // categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            text:   'Availability'
            },
            min: 0,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color:  '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix:  ' PCs'
        },
        legend: {
                layout:  'vertical',
                align:  'right',
                verticalAlign:  'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name:   'Available',
            color: '#00FF00',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17),
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 10],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 8],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 7],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 4],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 4],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 7],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 33],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 12],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 37],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 1],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 36],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 36],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 33],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 32],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 32],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 32],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 31],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 31],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 30],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 30],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 7],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 4],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 7],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 30],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 6],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 1],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 2],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 12],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 10],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 10],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 9],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 10],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 10],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 22],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 22],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 21), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 22],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 14],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 14],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 13]]
        }, {
            name:   'Unavailable',
            color: '#FF0000',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17),
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 30],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 32],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 33],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 36],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 38],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 37],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 37],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 36],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 37],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 33],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 12],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 12],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 12],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 13],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 22],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 17],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 16],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 20],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 19],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 29],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 25],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 22],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 22],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 17), 24],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 15],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 14],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 34],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 35],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 11],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 19), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 7],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 28],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 40],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 1],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 1],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 3],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 37],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 39],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 5],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 1],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 20), 0],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 14],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 18],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 21],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 23],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 26],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 27],[Date.UTC(2013,  9, 22), 27]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gakca/

Thanks,
David

Comment: Just in case, [reference to forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/post97649.html#p97649).

Comment: @PawełFus That's exactly what I did in my fiddle. The data in OP don't reflect the 5 minute time interval and it's too compact :)

Comment: I think you need to read once again my post from forum. Your time itnerval for points is one day, and you are setting a lot of points for one x-value. `[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17)` !== `[Date.UTC(2013, 9, 17, 10, 35)`

Comment: @PawełFus I am not the OP, and I am talking about the jsFiddle in my answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry! :) Take my vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to check the following jsFiddle, I made some changes based on your jsFiddle. But not quite sure if it's what you looking for or not.
http://jsfiddle.net/ethanph5/BC7Ks/2/

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    maxZoom: 7 * 24 * 3600000,
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    minTickInterval: 60 * 1000,
    minRange: 1800 * 1000
}
```

To get more zoom in, you should play around with [`minTickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minTickInterval) and [`minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange) to see what's the best setting for your need.

To add a scrollbar to x axis, here are the answers: [How to enable Highcharts scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432711/how-to-enable-highcharts-scrollbar) and [highcharts scroll through axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518686/highcharts-scroll-through-axis)

The key changes are:

In HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

In Javascript:

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Here is my updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanph5/BC7Ks/3/

Comment: Thanks, looks better.  I think the main thing I forgot was to add the hours and minutes to my data.  Is there a way to make the chart more "zoomed in", and add a horizontal scroll bar along the X-axis?

Comment: @user2296256 The answer is yes and yes. Check my updated answer. Don't hesitate to accept and/or vote up if it helps you :)