# Highcharts customization PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I am trying to customize the charts and give a demo to our clients for their approval.

Some final issues we are facing now are,

1. Issue: Is pagination possible in highcharts for column charts. Suppose if we have 50 or 100 columns.

   > How can we avoid our charts becoming crowded .

   For example take a look at this js fiddle

   > http://jsfiddle.net/justin69/4xSNU/1/
2. Issue: If we embed an image or logo in to a chart and try to export it using either either `jpg`/`jpeg` we get an error.

   > on jsfidlle  it works,
   >
   > but on our   localhost  it gives the following error message .

   `About to transcode 1 SVG file(s)   Converting
   551bc090a93c120f987375135e7744db.svg to
   temp/551bc090a93c120f987375135e7744db.jpg ... ... error  ( 
   SVGConverter.error.while.rasterizing.file)

   Error while converting SVG. SVG code for debugging:`

Comment: actaully i want to disable legend click on column drilldown but the legend disapper after i drill down and the legend click is enabled again :(

Comment: Can you edit your question please and remove those code blocks? it's difficult to read!

Comment: @Flukey yeah improved formatting now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Crowded Charts**

**a.** Have you tried rotating the labels? This would significantly reduce the overcrowding on the labels that you earlier had.

Here's your Fiddle with the label mod: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/YSwk4/

**b.** If you have a lot of values and are restricted by space on the x-axis, you can convert your **column**-type chart to a **bar**-type chart.

Here's your Fiddle with the bar-chart mod: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/QqPha/

I would suggest using the first option as you can fit much more values in the same space and have a much cleaner chart.

Comment: Sorry, new user restrictions, so could not post the second part to the original answer above.

**2. Exporting Images**

Have you enabled images in the export? Have a look at the *Highcharts* demo for exporting charts with external images embedded on it: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/enableimages/

Hope these steps work out for you!

Comment: **Update**
 I believe scrolling is available for Highcharts, but you will have to use Highchart's *highstock.js* for that. Here is a similar question I found to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518686/highcharts-scroll-through-axis

Comment: Another method would be to create you own custom pagination - Split the series into half or into portions that you want (say 30 values per chart). Then add two hyperlinks, Previous and Next, after your chart container. The on click of these buttons would basically call the same chart but with the new data sets.
I'll try creating a fiddle for this, but why don't you give it a shot!

Comment: ya i have tried rotating the labels before :) but in normal case how could it be done . rotating is not am option for me  .

Comment: thanks your bar charts idea can really be helpfulle to me i will look in to it :)

Comment: but i believe that highstock.js cannot be used commercially even if u have highcharts license is it so ?

Comment: @Rinzler Yes, Highstocks and Highcharts are two different products so you'll need to buy a separate license for it, if you want to use it commerically!

Answer (score 8):

Let's see if I can help you...

### "Chart Crowded"

I can imagine three ways to avoid your charts to be "crowded":

### Method 1: Let the user choose what to see.

Either hide adding `visible: false` to some or all your series, using this will allow the user to choose what data he wants to see. For example:

```
series: [
            {
                name: ...,
                data: ...,
                visible: false
            },
            ...
        ]
```

---

If you choose this example you could could also think about adding a button to show/hide all, that you can achieve by using:

Hide everything:

```
for(i=0; i < chart.series.length-1; i++)
    chart.series[i].hide();
```

Show everything:

```
for(i=0; i < chart.series.length-1; i++)
    chart.series[i].show();
```

---

### Method 2: Zoomming your way out of the problem

**In alternative** you can use `zoomType: 'x'` in your chart allowing the user to zoom and see the data in detail, the user can then scroll with the zoom to the left and right of the chart or reset the zoom and choose another point to see.

---

### Method 3: overflow

**In alternative** you can create a giant chart and use overflow to allow the chart div to be scrollable, or hide the overflow and manage the `scrollX` & `scrollY` trough jQuery.

---

**Can you provide the code or link to fiddle of the svg example so I can check your code and see if I can help you with that?**

Thank you.

Comment: hi i have added an fiddle if u can show how to do it :) am a newbie so

Comment: ya giant chart can accomadte all data but we need to have all the data in 400*400 pixel . so thats not possible .

Comment: i would have prefferd some kind of scrollbar like in highstock they have . i wish that was implemted in highcharts too if the chart was crowded . i upvoted ur answer will try other two can u tweak my fiddle

Comment: Hello @Rinzler, I will be updating my answer soon. Let me check. Thanks.