# Highcharts / Highstock scroll bar and Zoom issue

Tags: jquery, scroll, zooming, highcharts

I managed to enable a scroll bar in Highcharts as suggested **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518686/highcharts-scroll-through-axis)**.

Now I am struck with strange problems.

**Reset Zoom** button is not shown after zooming the chart. But when i disabled scroll in my chart, it worked as a charm. How do i bring back the reset zoom button and why it is not enabled after zooming ? Did not find any error in console too.

Next, if the scroll is enabled, the scroll bar **overlaps with the legend box**. Anyways i can have my legend's `layout` set to `horizontal`. But how to avoid this overlapping ?

Here is what I have tried,

**[With scroll bar](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/JDa7t/1/)**  and  **[Without a scroll bar](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/yKCYg/3/)**

Hope someone out there can help me sort it out.

Comment: You can try "position" and "relativeTo" properties of chart.resetZoomButton. Anywy, I have already try them and did not managed to solve your issue - you can report this as a bug.

Comment: @gotqn, thanks for your time. I will look forward to report this as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Highcharts. This is fixed and will be available in the next release of Highcharts. As of now, it can be fixed temporarily using the ***[beta](http://github.highcharts.com/master/highstock.src.js)*** version of their js.

And the scroll bar, fixed by adding a `y` parameter as in

```
legend: {
        shadow: true,
        y: -20
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `navigator` instead.
`scrollBar` isn't an option for `Highstocks`.

```
navigator: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qCc2Q/).