# How to make highcharts scrollable horizontally when having big range in x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I am generating my x-axis and y-axis data dynamically and displaying highcharts, but the chart becomes messy when the x-axis range is high with small intervals.

How do I make highcharts to make normal horizontally scrollable graph?

Here is what I am using right now:

[image]

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

//CODE FOR HIGHCHARTS JS
function makeChart() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Banana',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: banana.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: xlist
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'No. of C'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: 'C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: $("#repoSelector option:selected").text(),
            data: ylist
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried solution at this but it dint work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518686/highcharts-scroll-through-axis

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two ways to achieve a scroll bar.

### Option 1

You will need to use ***`highstock.js`***  and instead of rendering a stock chart, you have to render a ***highchart***.

Then enable the scroll bar

```
  scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    }
```

Check the API for scroll bar and related operations [**`here`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar).

[**`Here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/1/) I have fiddled an example.

### Option 2

Try setting `min` & `max` attributes to the `x-axis`.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: [...],
            min: 0,
            max:9
}
```

Displays 10 categories in x-axis at a stretch, adding a scroll for the rest of the categories.
find the fiddled example [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/293/).

Comment: i tried editing it in fiddle according to my need but its not working: http://jsfiddle.net/kUSyF/4/

Comment: @lemarc: There are a few issues such as an extra ',' at the end of the series data and you missed a '}]' at the end of series. I have edited your chart here . http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/5/

Comment: though this will do my work but it would have been better if I could remove zoom and make it scrollable, i.e. first appearance should be normal without x-axis element overlapping each other.

Comment: for commercial projects with license to highcharts, does the use of this scrollbar component require an additional license to highstocks to be purchased?

Comment: @slugslog Suppose so.

Comment: can i use option 2 (min and max) with `xAxis:{type: "datetime"}` ? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

To enable scrollbar in x-axis, try this

```
xAxis: {
  categories: xlist,
  min: 0,
  max: 4,
  scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
  },
  },
```

Check the jfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/BhavyaAprajita/zja90wf2/1/

Also, make sure that you import the highstock library

```
src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"
```

Comment: How can we import `src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"`in React.

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock');
```

comment this if you have

```
// import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

change xAxis to like this

```
xAxis : {
               categories: [],
                min:0,
                max:9,
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
require('highcharts/highmaps') instead of require('highcharts') in imports<br>
@NgModule({<br>
    ...<br>
   imports: [<br>
    BrowserModule, <br>
     ChartModule.forRoot( <br>
      require('highcharts/highmaps')<br>
      ],<br>
})
```