# How to set scrollbar for charts in highcharts.js ?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I use highcharts.js and I need to create a scrollbar to scroll the chart.
Scroll bar itself I created using draggable component of jquery-ui.
I do not know how to make chart with my scroll scrolls.
I would really appreciate if I get some advice.

Comment: this answer may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706068/how-to-make-highcharts-scrollable-horizontally-when-having-big-range-in-x-axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use highcharts but with using highstock.js and then enable scrollbar.

Comment: Yes, i can use it.
But it gives to me just a native scrollbar.

Comment: In other cases when your scrollbar is printed, you can use setExtremes nd then have influeone on the chart. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

Answer (score 0):

you can create a highchart even with highstock.js . In Highstock you are having the feature of scrollbar. This scroll bar can be customizable.