# Highcharts not rendering properly with too many series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

luckily highcharts is been integrated to the application but the problem i am facing now is the rendering of the data..it works fine with the small amount of series but as the series goes on increasing the size of the graph displayed gets smaller n eventually nothing is visible..i am confused whether its a css problem or something else
here is how it looks:

[image]

any help I would be glad!!

Comment: Please add image and code.

Comment: How would you like it to act? take more space (height)?

Comment: I see two solutions in your case: **a)** increase height for the chart, **b)** set [`maxHeight`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.maxHeight) for the legend (e.g. 100px).

Comment: @Ondkloss ya i would want it to adjust its height automatically based on the content..

Comment: @PawełFus if i set the max height then would it become too static?

Comment: Which part will become too static? It is limitation for the legend, so you will make space in your chart for the data.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an issue with HighCharts but rather the way you are displaying your information. If your container/div has a certain size, HighCharts tries to figure out what would be the best way to display the information based on your parameters.

As you said, it looks fine with less data, so in that case, you just need to put in a scroll option in highcharts or a zoom in option, which allows you to display that information. Another option is to get rid of your legend, so you can see more of the chart (as long as your tooltip is being utilized), but after more data, the issue will reside again with that option.

**Option 1 - Scrolling:**

[How to make highcharts scrollable horizontally when having big range in x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706068/how-to-make-highcharts-scrollable-horizontally-when-having-big-range-in-x-axis)

**Option 2 - Zooming:**

```
chart: {
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
        }
```

[Demo from Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/zoomtype-x/)