# Highcharts - bar chart columns too thin with too many series

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am developing a angular2 application using highcharts, but i have a problem about showing a bar chart. I have applied their sample code of highcharts to my application. It works. But when i added extra series to the chart, the columns becomes unreasonably too thin. [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mch9z.png)

I separately tried the sample code on JSfiddle with adding extra series to the code. It works however. `...` [workable example](http://jsfiddle.net/d98pukuo/)

Comment: One thing you can do is to set fixed point width (columns might overlap in this case) or you can decrease the space between groups of column - see groupPadding to 0 - http://jsfiddle.net/d98pukuo/1/

Comment: Show us your code, or a live example of the version that is not working. I would assume it is an issue of the data structure and/or grouping settings. Also, please clarify - the "workable example" in your post is an acceptable result for you, or not?

Comment: @morganfree I tried to set fixed point width and groupPadding to 0, but the chart columns still are thin. I think it is not a styling problem. This problem exists only when the number of series is more than 10.

Comment: @jlbriggs The "workable example" in my post is an acceptable result for me. I copied the same code from "working example" to my application, but i got "my result" version.

Comment: Clearly something is different in how you've implemented it - seeing what it is that is different is the only way we're going to solve the problem :) Ideally you can recreate the problem in a fiddle. I would focus on comparing your data structure to the data structure in the demo (especially if the other code is copied from the demo).

Comment: One note, in the image you posted you have stacking option enabled - http://jsfiddle.net/d98pukuo/2/ - but it stil does not create think columns by default.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced a very similar issue and even posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346977/highcharts-columns-are-thin-when-10-series-displayed) about it.
The solution seems to be pretty easy - for me the problem was in outdated highcharts (5.0.8) and highcharts modules(exporting, boost, highcharts-more, heatmap) (v. 5.0.8), so if you cannot reproduce your local behavior in jsfiddle try setting particular version of highcharts libraries like I've done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/sbx081j5/3/).

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.8/highcharts.js"></script>
```

However when I updated to highcharts 5.0.14 the [problem disappeared](http://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/sbx081j5/4/).

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

The issue was with a boost.js module, in particular with `seriesThreshold` property was set to 10 by default (now it is 50). Please find a detailed answer with example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365043/3556456)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind scrollable high-chart then this issue can be resolved.
Instead of Highchart use HighStock library, it will provide additional "scrollbar" option which you can combine with X-axis [max](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max) option to show the data properly.

Here is the Updated Link for [same code](http://jsfiddle.net/5x1ydcf6/10)

```
 scrollbar:{
    enabled:true
},
xAxis: {
     max:0
// rest of the code}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706068/how-to-make-highcharts-scrollable-horizontally-when-having-big-range-in-x-axis) will be good help to go in details.