# Highcharts columns are thin when 10+ series displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, bar-chart, column-chart

I faced an issue very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453613/highcharts-bar-chart-columns-too-thin-with-too-many-series), but with categorized axis. 
The problem is that if I add too many series on the plot (more than 10 series) the columns become too thin and almost invisible even though there is enough place for them. 
Here is how the chart looks like when I have 12 series(11 for bars + 1 for line):
[image]
The same behaviour appears when I have 11 or 10 series, but when I reduce number of series to 9 (8 for bars + 1 for line) the chart looks absolutely normal:
[image]

However when I try recreating this bug with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/sbx081j5/1/) and the same highcharts version (5.0.8) I get absolutely correct behavior no matter how many series I use.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
    endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: false,
    title: {
                    text: 'xAxisLabel'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                },
        categories: ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69"],
                type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: [                {
                    title: {
                        text: 'SOme'
                    },
                    gridLineWidth: 0
                },
                {
                    title: {
                        text: 'text2'
                    },
                    opposite: true,
                    min: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0
                }],
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
//turboThreshold: 5000,
grouping: false,
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    shadow: false,
                    stickyTracking: false,
                    pointPlacement: 'on',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
        }
    },
    series:[{"name":"Brain Ischemia","data":[[32,1]],"color":"#CC6677","events":{}},{"name":"Cerebral Ischemia","data":[[6,1],[10,1]],"color":"#332288","events":{}},{"name":"Cerebrovascular Ischemia","data":[[32,1]],"color":"#999933","events":{}},{"name":"Focal Brain Ischemia","data":[[16,1]],"color":"#882255","events":{}},{"name":"Ischemia","data":[[8,1]],"color":"#44AA99","events":{}},{"name":"Non-ST Elevation Myocardial Infarction (NSTEMI)","data":[[1,1],[10,1]],"color":"#DDCC77","events":{}},{"name":"Not Confirmed","data":[[5,1]],"color":"#6699CC","events":{}},{"name":"Other","data":[[2,1],[6,1],[69,1]],"color":"#AA4499","events":{}},{"name":"ST Elevation Myocardial Infarction (STEMI)","data":[[1,2]],"color":"#4477AA","events":{}},{"name":"Stable Angina","data":[[0,3],[1,1],[4,1],[8,1],[14,1],[16,1],[28,1],[32,1],[36,1]],"color":"#88CCEE","events":{}},{"name":"Unstable Angina","data":[[1,2],[2,2],[5,1],[11,1],[12,1]],"color":"#117733","events":{}},{"name":"SUBJECTS","data":[[0,124],[1,124],[2,122],[3,122],[4,121],[5,121],[6,120],[7,118],[8,117],[9,116],[10,115],[11,114],[12,111],[13,110],[14,108],[15,106],[16,103],[17,102],[18,102],[19,100],[20,98],[21,98],[22,97],[23,96],[24,96],[25,96],[26,95],[27,95],[28,95],[29,93],[30,93],[31,93],[32,92],[33,91],[34,90],[35,89],[36,87],[37,86],[38,85],[39,84],[40,82],[41,81],[42,80],[43,80],[44,80],[45,80],[46,79],[47,77],[48,77],[49,77],[50,77],[51,77],[52,75],[53,73],[54,73],[55,71],[56,69],[57,69],[58,68],[59,67],[60,67],[61,67],[62,67],[63,67],[64,67],[65,67],[66,67],[67,66],[68,66],[69,66]],"color":"#000000","type":"line","yAxis":1,"dashStyle":"ShortDot","marker":{"enabled":false},"lineWidth":1,"pointPlacement":null,"stickyTracking":false}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.8/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.8/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by boost module, more specifically by `boost.seriesThreshold` property. It tells when the boost should kick in globally (see the source, https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.src.js). So, it has nothing to do with the version, simply before (until v5.0.12) `seriesThreshold` property was set to 10 by default (now it is 50).

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p6afwkb3/

Comment: By the way, do you have any ideas why boost module behaves like this? WHy does it breaks the chart?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347497/3556456), so this one should be fairly similar.
Stupid problem - an outdated highcharts library.

The problem didn't reproduced in jsfiddle, because I didn't included all modules that I have locally of particular version.