# Highcharts width continue expanding as chart width grows

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

What I am trying to achieve is to have a highcharts that width continues increasing as data points increase

currently, I have the following

AM using vuejs with highcharts but should be similar to jquery or others

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="overflow:auto"> //set overflow css
   <div id="container_h"></div>
<div>
```

now the script code that renders the highchart

```
      this.chart = Highcharts.chart('container_h', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: this.ranges
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total trucks'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: this.chartdata
            });
```

The above renders a chart with the

[image]

What I am looking forward to achieve is this: the highchart columns to have a fixed width which when it grows it creates a scroll on `x-axis` so something like this

[image]

that has a scroll area

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `highstock.js`.

There is already an answear there: [How to make highcharts scrollable horizontally when having big range in x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706068/how-to-make-highcharts-scrollable-horizontally-when-having-big-range-in-x-axis) thanks to @Gopinagh.R

> Two ways to achieve a scroll bar.
>
> ### Option 1
>
> You will need to use ***`highstock.js`***  and instead of rendering a
>   stock chart, you have to render a ***highchart***.
>
> Then enable the scroll bar
>
> ```
>   scrollbar: {
>         enabled: true
>     }
> ```
>
> Check the API for scroll bar and related operations http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/1/ I have fiddled an example.
>
> ### Option 2
>
> Try setting `min` & `max` attributes to the `x-axis`.
>
> ```
> xAxis: {
>             categories: [...],
>             min: 0,
>             max:9
> } Displays 10 categories in x-axis at a stretch, adding a scroll for the rest of the categories. find the fiddled example http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/kUSyF/293/
> ```