# Highcharts how to enable scrollbar without setting min or max

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

As mentioned here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706449/6181692) enabling scrollbars on a highchart axis is a fairly easy process of simply enabling following options:

### Option 1

You will need to use ***`highstock.js`***  and instead of rendering a stock chart, you have to render a ***highchart***.

Then enable the scroll bar

```
  scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    }
```

### Option 2

Try setting `min` & `max` attributes to the `x-axis`.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: [...],
            min: 0,
            max:9
}
```

one thing which is wrongly presented in the option 1, is that you have to perform one additional step of setting min/max as well, i.e. only enabling scrollbar isn't enough on its own.

The issue in my particular case is setting min and max, as the data is dynamic and its not possible to statically pre assign min and max.

[image]

Setting static max = 4 in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyh3pfrb/3/) does solves the issue for the static data set but this doesn't works well when number of data points is less than 4, e.g. in this case:

[image]

Also in my particular case users can expand chart in a modal, which is supposed to be bigger and show more information when smaller cards/charts are not enough for showing large amount of data sets, e.g. as mocked in [this demo](https://highcharts-cloning-chart-ckrbqj.stackblitz.io). In this case max = 4 is enough for the original chart height but not when expanded because it has more empty spaces when max = 4. So it would be better if we don't exactly need to set max, Instead if we can allow scroll by setting only bar width like following that makes more sense.

```
pointWidth: 25
pointPadding: 0.2
```

but setting only this doesn't work in the above fiddle.

[image]

P.S scrolling is not exactly enabled in the above stackBlitz gif, but it should be working fine in the provided [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-chart-ckrbqj) demo.

Is there any way we can enable scrollbars and not have to set min or max instead only pointWidth or may be some thing else and have scroll work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `max` property, but you can calculate and set it dynamically:

```
function setAxisMax() {
    var pointWidth = this.series[0].options.pointWidth,
        padding = 20;

    this.update({
        xAxis: {
            max: this.plotHeight / (pointWidth + padding) - 1
        }
    }, true, true, false);
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            load: setAxisMax
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/evmkqrcw/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

Comment: I ended up using having two max properties one for normal view and the other one for the expanded view and then switching between them on modal open. Also regarding the numeric values appearing in the X axis labels I suppressed them via over ridding label formatter and hiding all numeric values. Not clean workarounds but does the job for me. So setting max dynamically is kind of the only way. There is no way to enable scroll without setting min / max which is kind of bad.

Comment: Also dynamically only adding max when it makes more sense, really helped.