# Show only last 3 months data. other user can see on scrolling highcharts?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts

Show only last 3 months data. other user can see on scrolling highcharts?

i want to show last 20 intervals others in scroll bar... Its possible??
Check my fiddle here..

[https://jsfiddle.net/malai/bf3cmajk/](http://Fiddle)

Thanks,

Comment: anybody know answer?

Comment: like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518686/highcharts-scroll-through-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`HighCharts.js`** doesn't support scroll-bar feature. You need to use **`HighStocks.js`** library..

to do that you need to include **`HighStocks.js`**.

and in your JS

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', chartConfig) //chartConfig is you configuration.
```

to use ranges you need to specify `rangeSelector` I've put together the config to show range for 3 months.

```
rangeSelector: {
 inputEnabled: false,
 allButtonsEnabled: false,
 buttons: [{
   type: 'month',
   count: 3,
   text: '3month',
   dataGrouping: {
     forced: true,
     units: [
       ['month', [1]]
     ]
   }
 }],
 buttonTheme: {
   width: 60
 },
 selected: 0
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf3cmajk/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can post your suggestion in our uservoice service, where we gather all ideas from our users.

Ref:
- http://highcharts.uservoice.com